# Is possible automatic refresh filecontents* at each compilation of pgfplotstable?

Tags: compiling, pgfplotstable

Recently I observe, that at compiling of some tyble set width `pgfplotstable` generate `.csv` file, which is not changed at later changes in its source (in document preamble) compilation. Consequently I need to manually erase it.

I use (recent) MikTeX, WinEdt as editor and Windows 10 as OS.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{exponent-product={\cdot},
         output-decimal-marker={,}, 
         per-mode=symbol}

\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.csv}
Chem.; Avg. Conc.; Avg. Conc. Norm.; Conc. unit; Mass sum; Mass unit;
Ammonium ; 159083.33; 114450.21; \si{\micro\gram\per\liter};   2839.463; \si{\kilo\gram};
%Ammonium ; 159083.33; 114450.21; \si{\micro\gram\per\liter};   2839.463; \si{\kilo\gram};
%Ammonium ; 159083.33; 114450.21; \si{\micro\gram\per\liter};   2839.463; \si{\kilo\gram};
\end{filecontents*}

    \begin{document}
Some text here \si{\micro\gram\per\liter}, \si{\kilo\gram},

\captionof{table}{Some caption text}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period=true,
    header=has colnames,
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
         after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={
            after row=\bottomrule},
display columns/0/.style={string type, column type=l},%
display columns/3/.style={string type, column type=l},%
display columns/5/.style={string type, column type=l},%
    ]{mytable.csv}\par
    \end{document}
```

If I uncomment rows in `filecontents*` and compile above file again, the table is not changed until I manually erase it. Do I need some special settings in WinEdt to do erase old `.cvs` file or this can be achieved with some settings in document?

Comment: if you load the `filecontents` package, does your issue persist?

Comment: No, problem disappear! This is solution (to be honest, I didn't figured out what is purpose of this package, now I see, that it "should be" loaded by `pgfplotstable`). Please convert your comment to answer that I can vote and accept it!

Comment: glad it fixed it :) I have a feeling there may be a duplicate somewhere; I'll take a look, and if I can't find one, I'll post an answer if you like :)

Comment: before posting my questions, I search through SE ... if there is an "original", it is well hidden :-). You just make answer from your comment!

Comment: @Zarko There is a reason while the behviour is non standard and you have to load a package. Many people have overwritten their own files by mistake because they were not aware of what or why something happens or blindly ran examples.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I agree with you, however, when I begin use `pgfplotstable` (I still learning it), I didn't found (or I miss it?)  any information about this. I saw some examples in SE with which load this package but didn't figured out why it is needed. Now all is clear ... to the next problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [`filecontents`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/filecontents) package, which in turn quotes from `ltclass.dtx` (the emphasis is my own)

> The environment filecontents is intended for passing the contents of
>   packages, options, or other files along with a document in a single
>   file. It has one argument, which is the name of the file to create. **If
>   that file already exists (maybe only in the current directory if the
>   OS supports a notion of a ‘current directory’ or ‘default directory’)
>   then nothing happens (except for an information message) and the body
>   of the environment is bypassed.** Otherwise, the body of the environment is written verbatim to the file name given as the first argument,
>   together with some comments about how it was produced.

Slightly further down the documentation,

> The filecontents package provides a hacked-up version of the filecontents and
>   filecontents* environments that lifts the two restrictions stated above

As such, your problem can be solved simply by loading the `filecontents` package:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
```